# cordova, correct way to removing plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I must remove some plugin in cordova to run the android platform,
So to do this I am starting to remove one of them 
("cordova-plugin-api-call"),

Then I try to remove another plugin ("oSDK-plugin") but the terminal return me the message:

Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-api-call". Please try adding it again.

So which is the correct way to remove correctly the plugins?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can list all your plugins

cordova plugin list

Then remove plugin which you want

cordova plugin remove PLUGIN_NAME

Comment: can i remove multiple plugins such as:

cordova pugin remove PLUGINNAME1 PLUGINNAME2 etc...?

Comment: I didn't try it. Probably you don't have big number of plugins so you can remove them one by one

Comment: maybe the topic is not clear, but the problem is that after the first plugin uninstall, when i'm launching the second i have the console error Error: Cannot find plugin.xml with reference of the first plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the platforms, plugins and node_modules directories. Then run `cordova prepare`, it will build all the project from scratch.